# calculate $[T^t]^{b^{\ast }}_{g^{\ast }}$ directly from $T^t(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Let $V=P_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the corresponding basis $b= \left \{ 1,x \right \}$ and $g= \left \{ e_1,e_2 \right \}$ We define the linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ $$T(p)=(p(0)-2p(1),p(0)+{p}'(0))$$

if $f \in  W^{\ast } $ with: $$f(a,b)=a-2b$$

Calculate $T^t(f)$ and $[T^t]^{b^{\ast }}_{g^{\ast }}$.

$T^t(f)=f(T)$ then $f(T)=p(0)-2p(1)-2(p(0)+{p(0)}')$ plugging in the $b$ basis we get $-3,-4$ so

$T^t(f)=-3a-4b$
but if i want to calculate $[T^t]^{b^{\ast }}_{g^{\ast }}$ it's not working. What I mean, if I put $T^t(f(e_1))=-3$ and $T^t(f(e_2))=-4$ which gives me this matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
-3 &-4 \\ 
 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and I should get  $[T^t]^{b^{\ast }}_{g^{\ast }}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &1 \\ 
 -2& 1
\end{pmatrix}$

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the person voting to close this as "Needs more focus" could explain how they think the question could be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $T^t(f) = f \circ T \in V^*$, and then $T^t(f)$ is the function from $V$ to $\mathbb R$ that maps each $p \in V$ to the real number $$\begin{align} T^t(f)(p) &= f(T(p)) = f(p(0)-2p(1),p(0)+p'(0)) \\ &= \big( p(0)-2p(1) \big) -2 \big( p(0)+p'(0) \big) \\ &= -p(0)-2p(1)-2p'(0). \end{align}$$ Now, $g^* = \{\pi_1,\pi_2\}$ where $\pi_i \in W^*$ $(i=1,2)$ is the function from $W$ to $\mathbb R$ that maps each $(x_1,x_2) \in W$ to $x_i$, that is, $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate (this is by merely definition of dual basis). Hence, you need to compute $T^t(\pi_1)$ and $T^t(\pi_2)$ (note that these are functions) and then write it as a linear combination of the functions $p_1$ and $p_2$ (what is a linear combination of functions?), where $b^* = \{p_1,p_2\}$ is the dual basis of $b$.

I hope this clarify the things a little!